# importing tensorflow raise pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py error

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

I'm in Windows Server 2012 using Python 3.5.4.
I installed tensorflow (NOT GPU) through pip, but when I import it it raises such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

- I've already installed Visual Studio 2017 "before" to install tensorflow;
- In C:\Windows\System32 is present MSVCP140.DLL
- The MSVCP140.DLL path is already present in PATH variable

Any suggestion on how to solve such issue?

Comment: yes it is, thank you! Should I delete this question?

Comment: Already done ;)